# Cannot resolve symbol EvaluatorUtil

Tags: java, android, rapidminer, pmml

I am very new in both pmml and android field.I had follow the code in https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android/tree/master/pmml-android-example but EvaluatorUtil symbol cannot be resolved.So I follow suggestion in android and import org.jpmml.evaluator.EvaluatorUtil but now createEvaluator symbol cannot be resolved

.

private Evaluator createEvaluator() throws Exception {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

```
    try(InputStream is = assetManager.open("pmml.pmml.ser")){
        return EvaluatorUtil.createEvaluator(is);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to import the library following the instructions in the [repo](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android).

Comment: Thanks....I had already run mvn clean install...if i use <packaging>jar</packaging>,then there is a warning([WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
)but if i changed jar to pom, then there is no any warning occurred.I think I already followed the steps in repo....I am very new in android,sorry for any mistake...thanks

Comment: I had download the zip and put the zip in libs folder.Then add the library(zip) in project structure.I had not sure that this step successfully add the library to my project?Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason this is tagged "rapidminer"?

Comment: @ChristianKönig I import the pmml model from rapidminer....I am not sure whether there is any effect on my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use gradle you need to import library like this in your app gradle file :

```
implementation group: 'org.jpmml', name: 'jpmml-evaluator-spark', version: '1.0.0'
```

then Sync and it's all :)

Comment: Thanks, I had try with this idea but it still can't worked for me.Cannot resolve method 'createEvaluator(java.io.InputStream).Do you have any idea?thanks so much....I will try all out

Comment: Did you import org.jpmml.evaluator.spark.EvaluatorUtil; in your class ?

Comment: After adding import org.jpmml.evaluator.spark.EvaluatorUtil; There is an error: cannot access JAXBException
class file for javax.xml.bind.JAXBException not found...May I know how can I solved this?

Comment: Could you try to add implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1' in your app gradle ?

Comment: Thanks...yup....I tried it and this problem is solved but currently gt this error (    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream) Is that the system cannot read my pmml file ? or?Application can run but the evaluation result didnt coming out

Comment: Maybe your file is empty or corrupted.. do you have more information about the error in your log cat ?

Comment: the error in logcat too long..can't post here...can I have your email....I can send the code to you...If u dunt mind or I attached my email here?.Thanks..if i use <packaging>jar</packaging>,then there is a warning([WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion! )but if i changed jar to pom, then there is no any warning occurred.Currently i put pom for my packaging to avoid the warning...Does it have any effect to this problem?Thanks